# Delete an Item (Row) from Access Database C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to program a delete button that will delete a row when it's selected.
Yet, everything I find on the internet is a bunch of _ _ _ _

I am creating my program on Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Using a MS Access Database

The form contains multiple list-boxes, each with their own piece of the row data.

I can add rows to the table through my programs GUI, but cannot seem to delete them!

I want to delete the selected item, and also to delete all rows on-click of a different button.

Thanks

**NOTE:** I AM NOT USING SQL BEFORE YOU DECIDE TO GIVE ME ANSWERS IN SQL..

It should look *"something"* like this:

```
dbnameDataSet.tableName deltableNameRow;
deltableNameRow = dbnameDataSet.FindByItemID( SelectedItem.lstID );

deltableNameRow.Delete();
this.tableNameTableAdapter.Update(this.dbnameDataSet.tableName);
```

However, My skills in C# are somewhat limited, so I can only write pseudo for most obstacles.
I have the mind to figure out the problems, but not the library of termanology and understood language to write it myself at the moment.

Please can you figure this out for me.

This is how I currently add items (Working):

```
dboKanadaDataSet.ProductsRow newProductsRow;
newProductsRow = dboKanadaDataSet.Products.NewProductsRow();

newProductsRow.ProductName = txtItem.Text;
newProductsRow.ListPrice = txtPrice.Text;

this.dboKanadaDataSet.Products.Rows.Add(newProductsRow);
this.productsTableAdapter.Update(this.dboKanadaDataSet.Products);
```

Any contributions are very welcome.

Muchas Gracias, Merci, Danke, Xie4 Xie4, Thanks!
Josh.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (It's not quite what I wanted, but its working for the task.)

Using the 'Binding Navigator' tool found in the toolbox.

It give the user the following bar:

[image: Navigation Bar for Data Rows of an embedded database (c# in my case)]

Then, double-click the 'Save' button and add this code to your form:

```
    private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveRow();            
    }
    public void saveRow()
    {
        // Created this as a separate function that can be called later
        // ... with a simple 'saveRow();' call. (removes code repetition)

        // Note: The '55555' and '66666' are to be replaced
        // ... by your dataset names (55555) and table name (66666)

        this.Validate();
        this.55555BindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.55555TableAdapter.Update(55555DataSet.66666);
    }
```

To remove items, simply double-click the 'delete' icon and add the following line of code:

```
        {
            saveRow();
        }
```